# Reformating text when no more space

Tags: html, css, html-framework-7

I have this html where there is the main phrase and a subphrase where they are both separated by a br.But when the screen is smaller the main phrase will break and push the subphrase out of the div.

I already tried to not let the phrase break but that would make her not fully visible , thats something i cannot do.

I would like to know if its possible when the main phrase doesnt have more space(this is in the smaller screens) make her fontsize smaller so its fully viisible, that means she will be with a font size smaller will make the br followed by the subphrase OR delete the br and the main phrase will brake and will be followed by the subphrase without the br (in the same line)(Im using framework7)

https://jsfiddle.net/ts45r7zn/

html:

```
<div class="grand-parent">
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
   <span class="">hello im the main phrase</span>
   <br>
   <span class="">i want to igore br or main phrase get smaller</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grandparent {
 height: 30%;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden; 
}

.parent {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 55%;
 width: 100%;
}

.child{
 background-color: rgba(132, 29, 62,0.7);
 height: 31%;
 width: 30%;
 padding-left: 5%;
}
```

i prefer not use jquery.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you didn't want the break you shouldn't have put it in. I suggest you re-think the HTML. But it' still unclear how this is supposed to look.

Comment: Does the parent have to be that specific height? Is there going to be something above the parent?

Comment: the gran-parent (see fidle) wlll be 30% of the pageheight both the parent and child will also have percentage height.(I failed to mention that im using framework7)

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled entirely with CSS.

To make the text smaller on small screens, use a [`@media` query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to adjust the font-size, like this:

HTML:

```
<span class="text">I'm the main phrase</span>
<br>
<span class="text">i want to igore br or main phrase get smaller</span>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

`max-width: 320px` would be for an iPhone size screen. Android is a bit larger at `360px` or `400px`.

Comment: There is a way to do that but only if the text overflows out of the div?

Comment: Check out [FitText https://github.com/adactio/FitText.js](https://github.com/adactio/FitText.js)